# Django: using python methods

Tags: python, django, methods

I'm trying to truncate my urls that are being populated into html table like so:

```
{% for x in queryset %}
<tr> 
<td>{{x.LINK}}</td>
</tr>
```

so that i.e 'www.google.com' becomes 'google'. How to achieve it? In python it would be straight forward with `.split('.')` method but here I'm confused.
Or maybe it would be simplier to do all the data modifications before I query them in django?

Comment: You should be able to use pretty much any valid Python inside `{% %}` blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Just noticed your example contains a simplified but malformed URL. This simpler template tag will work for URLs formatted like 'www.google.com':

```
@register.simple_tag()
def get_domain_name_from_url(url):
    return url.split('.')[-2]
```

---

If you're dead-set on doing this in the template, you can make a custom [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/):

As long as your URLs are properly formatted (e.g. "https://www.google.com/"), this should do the trick:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

from urllib.parse import urlparse

@register.simple_tag()
def get_domain_name_from_url(url):
    parsed_url = urlparse(url)
    netloc = parsed_url[1]
    domain_name = netloc.split('.')[-2]
    return domain_name
```

How it works:

1. `urlparse` parses the domain into a 6-item named tuple.
2. The second tuple item (`parsed_url[1]`) is a string containing the network location part of the URL (e.g. `"www.google.com"`)
3. Split the string into its component parts using `split('.')`, and return the second-last item in the list (`"google"`). By getting the part before the TLD (`.com`), we avoid any issues that arise if we work from the beginning. (e.g. if the URL does not contain `www`, we will want the first item in the list, not the second. By starting with the TLD and working backwords, we should always get the domain name.)

Save the code in a file named `[your_django_project]/[your_app]/templatetags/get_domain_name.py`.

Make sure the app is in your `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`.

Restart the server. (Don't forget this part. The server registers your template tags when it starts.)

Now, in your template, you can load the code:

```
{% load get_domain_name %}
{% get_domain_name_from_url x.LINK %}
```